# how to modify element of list in python

Tags: list

Given a list of filenames, we want to rename all the files with extension .hpp to the extension h. To do this, we would like to generate a new list called newfilenames, consisting of the new filenames. Fill in the blanks in the code using any of the methods you’ve learned thus far, like a for loop or a list comprehension.

```py
filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]
# Generate newfilenames as a list containing the new filenames
# using as many lines of code as your chosen method requires.
```

---

```py
print(newfilenames) 
# Should be ["program.c", "stdio.h", "sample.h", "a.out", "math.h", "hpp.out"]
```

Comment: Please do not add an assignment question straight away to stackoverflow for answers. If you have tried out something, then include the source code so that people can assist you in a better way.

Answer (score 9):

```
newfilenames = [e.replace('.hpp','.h') for e in filenames]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]

newfilenames=[]

for filename in filenames:
    if filename.endswith(".hpp"):
        filename = filename.replace(".hpp", ".h")
        newfilenames.append(filename)
        
    else:
        newfilenames.append(filename)


print(newfilenames)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]
# Generate newfilenames as a list containing the new filenames
# using as many lines of code as your chosen method requires.
newfilenames = [word.replace("hpp","h") if word.endswith("hpp") else word for word in filenames ]

print(newfilenames) 
# Should be ["program.c", "stdio.h", "sample.h", "a.out", "math.h", "hpp.out"]
```

Comment: Thank You, Sir, ill try to do my best.

Answer (score 0):

```
filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]

newfilenames = []
for names in filenames:
    if names.endswith('.hpp'):
        newfilenames.append(names[:-2])
        continue
    newfilenames.append(names)


print(newfilenames)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]

newfilenames=[]
for x in filenames:
    if x.endswith(".hpp"):
        newfilenames.append(x.replace(".hpp",".h"))
    else:
        newfilenames.append(x)     

print(newfilenames)
```

Comment: Please add explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]
newfilenames=[]
for filename in filenames:
    if '.hpp' in filename:
        index=filename.index(".")
        newfile=filename[:index]+".h"
        newfilenames.append(newfile)
    else:
        newfilenames.append(filename)

print(filenames)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While this answer may solve the OP's issues, it's recommended to provide an explanation about the written code

Comment: Thanks for suggestion! Will do from next time.

Answer (score 0):

```py
newfilenames = [ f.rstrip("pp") if f.endswith(".hpp") else f for f in filenames ]
```

Instead of `str.replace()`, I prefer using `str.rstrip()` and `str.endswith()` to take care of potential edge cases.

Answer (score -1):

```
newfilenames = []
for names in filenames:
    if names.endswith('.hpp'):
        newfilenames.append(names[:-2])
        continue
    newfilenames.append(names)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
def pig_latin(text):
    v = text.split()
    t = []
    for x in v:
        i = str(x[1:]) + str(x[0][0]) + 'ay'
        t.append(i)
    return t
    
print(pig_latin("hello how are you")) # Should be "ellohay owhay reaay ouyay"
print(pig_latin("programming in python is fun")) # Should be "rogrammingpay niay ythonpay siay unfay"
```

Comment: Is this an answer to this question?